# LDAP authentication with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap

I am getting error while login into the ldap server with credentials.

My securityconfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("(employeeID={0})")
        .userSearchBase("DC=xxx,DC=xxx")

    .contextSource()
    .url("ldap://localhost:389")
    .managerDn("sxxx")
    .managerPassword("xxx")
   .and()
    .passwordCompare()
        .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");

    }
 @Bean
        public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
            return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:389"), "DC=xxx,DC=xxx");
    }
```

I am using spring security for ldap authentication. I am getting below error:

Reason:

```
[LDAP: error code 16 - 00002080: AtrErr: DSID-03080155, #1: 0:
00002080: DSID-03080155, problem 1001 (NO_ATTRIBUTE_OR_VAL), data 0,
Att 23 (userPassword) ]; nested exception is
javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16
- 00002080: AtrErr: DSID-03080155, #1: 0: 00002080: DSID-03080155, problem 1001 (NO_ATTRIBUTE_OR_VAL), data 0, Att 23 (userPassword) ];
```

Comment: From the exception, it seems that your ldap database does not have the attribute named `userPassword`. Have you verified that the attributes you are putting in your configuration  are named exactly like in your ldap?

Comment: @theLearner Thank you. I was able to authenticate by binding it to the "sAMAccountName"

Comment: I have posted the above suggestion as my answer. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the exception, it seems that your ldap database does not have the attribute named `userPassword`. Have you verified that the attributes you are putting in your configuration are named exactly like in your ldap? 
Your problem will be solved by providing the exact attributes name.